# For Firebase AB test experiments, are activation events used retroactively?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

When you set up an AB test experiment on Firebase, you can pick an activation event to determine who can get placed in the experiment. What I'm unsure of is: is it everybody who ever triggered that event or is it just people who trigggered the event AFTER the experiment is made live? The docs seem ambiguous on this.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config

> Optionally, set an activation event to ensure that only users who have first triggered some Analytics event are counted in your experiment, then click Next.

I need to know since I'd like to only target new users that triggered this event, not users from before the experiment started. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activation events are the events logged by the app in the last 30 days, regardless of users. If you can see it in your Events page, then it should be available on A/B Testing console as an activation event.

If a user satisfies the targeting criteria and calls fetch > activate or fetchAndActivate method, then the user will be part of the experiment. Logging the activation event will make sure that the data logged by the user will be included in the experiment.